# SIGABRT crash on iOS app

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

I am trying to test an iOS app on device.

I have included as much of the crash log as Stack Overflow will let me.

This error only occurs when the location permission modal pops up. Before I can even select to allow or deny location-based services, the entire app crashes.

This is built in PhoneGap so the stacktrace doesn't really help me, however I believe I've narrowed it down to the following line:

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(updatePosition, fail, {maximumAge: 1500000, enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 15000});
```

Which is using the following library:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation

Disabling it causes the prompt for geolocation to never come up (predictably) and the app to never crash. Putting it in try/catch blocks does not have the same effect - it still crashes with try/catch blocks.

I am relatively new to iOS testing - what could this be? Previously I never had this problem - it just started recently.

Here's the error report:

```
Incident Identifier: 2659EAAD-880B-43D4-8FC8-DA72A339A8FE
CrashReporter Key:   6abf4dea428e61799976d0d99f76954ba96688a6
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Process:             AppNameHere [5003]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E9BB5F67-5428-4C81-B769-218AC25F4015/AppNameHere.app/AppNameHere
Identifier:          com.company.tasks
Version:             1.0.0 (1.0.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.company.tasks [1147]


Date/Time:           2017-08-01 20:43:50.7592 -0400
Launch Time:         2017-08-01 20:43:21.3956 -0400
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.3 (14G60)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x192212fe0 0x190c74538 0x192212ca8 0x1001e3ac8 0x1000cd750 0x1000dbf14 0x1000dbc1c 0x192cf0c4c 0x1921c1aa4 0x1921c17a8 0x1921c1068 0x1921bec8c 0x1920eeda4 0x193b59074 0x1983a9c9c 0x1000bc7d8 0x1910fd59c)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019120d014 0x1911ee000 + 126996
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912d7264 0x1912d2000 + 21092
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001911819c4 0x191120000 + 399812
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000190c4d1b0 0x190c4c000 + 4528
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000190c66c04 0x190c4c000 + 109572
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000190c74820 0x190c6c000 + 34848
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000190c635d4 0x190c4c000 + 95700
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000190c631a8 0x190c4c000 + 94632
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000190c746f8 0x190c6c000 + 34552
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001920eee10 0x1920e6000 + 36368
10  GraphicsServices                0x0000000193b59074 0x193b4d000 + 49268
11  UIKit                           0x00000001983a9c9c 0x198335000 + 478364
12  appnamehere                         0x00000001000bc7d8 0x1000b8000 + 18392
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001910fd59c 0x1910f9000 + 17820

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912d2ca8 0x1912d2000 + 3240

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912d2ca8 0x1912d2000 + 3240

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001911ef224 0x1911ee000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001911ef09c 0x1911ee000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001921c0e90 0x1920e6000 + 896656
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001921beae4 0x1920e6000 + 887524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001920eeda4 0x1920e6000 + 36260
5   Foundation                      0x0000000192c09db4 0x192bfd000 + 52660
6   Foundation                      0x0000000192c2ab84 0x192bfd000 + 187268
7   UIKit                           0x0000000198d33830 0x198335000 + 10479664
8   Foundation                      0x0000000192d07318 0x192bfd000 + 1090328
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912d568c 0x1912d2000 + 13964
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912d559c 0x1912d2000 + 13724
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912d2cb4 0x1912d2000 + 3252

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001911ef224 0x1911ee000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001911ef09c 0x1911ee000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001921c0e90 0x1920e6000 + 896656
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001921beae4 0x1920e6000 + 887524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001920eeda4 0x1920e6000 + 36260
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001928fbdf4 0x19281a000 + 925172
6   Foundation                      0x0000000192d07318 0x192bfd000 + 1090328
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912d568c 0x1912d2000 + 13964
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912d559c 0x1912d2000 + 13724
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912d2cb4 0x1912d2000 + 3252

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019120d314 0x1911ee000 + 127764
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019112c8b0 0x191120000 + 51376
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x0000000190c3d3c4 0x190bf6000 + 291780
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000196aa2d2c 0x1960e9000 + 10198316
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000196aa1d6c 0x1960e9000 + 10194284
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000196aa1ba8 0x1960e9000 + 10193832
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000196aa1a50 0x1960e9000 + 10193488
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000196aa2e30 0x1960e9000 + 10198576
8   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000196aa2d5c 0x1960e9000 + 10198364
9   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000196aa300c 0x1960e9000 + 10199052
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912d568c 0x1912d2000 + 13964
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912d559c 0x1912d2000 + 13724
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912d2cb4 0x1912d2000 + 3252

Thread 6 name:  WebThread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019120ce64 0x1911ee000 + 126564
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912d8b8c 0x1912d2000 + 27532
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912d8d94 0x1912d2000 + 28052
3   WebCore                         0x0000000196dc3330 0x196d7e000 + 283440
4   WebCore                         0x0000000196dc3290 0x196d7e000 + 283280
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001921c09a8 0x1920e6000 + 895400
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001921be630 0x1920e6000 + 886320
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001921bec18 0x1920e6000 + 887832
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001920eeda4 0x1920e6000 + 36260
9   WebCore                         0x0000000196dc0d3c 0x196d7e000 + 273724
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912d568c 0x1912d2000 + 13964
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912d559c 0x1912d2000 + 13724
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912d2cb4 0x1912d2000 + 3252

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019120da88 0x1911ee000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912d2fd0 0x1912d2000 + 4048
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912d2cac 0x1912d2000 + 3244

Thread 8 name:  WebCore: LocalStorage
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019120ce1c 0x1911ee000 + 126492
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912d4814 0x1912d2000 + 10260
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001960f69a4 0x1960e9000 + 55716
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000196a89a68 0x1960e9000 + 10095208
4   WebKitLegacy                    0x00000001980310a8 0x197f9d000 + 606376
5   WebKitLegacy                    0x0000000198033d40 0x197f9d000 + 617792
6   WebKitLegacy                    0x0000000198033348 0x197f9d000 + 615240
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001960f2f7c 0x1960e9000 + 40828
8   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001960f2e8c 0x1960e9000 + 40588
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912d568c 0x1912d2000 + 13964
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912d559c 0x1912d2000 + 13724
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912d2cb4 0x1912d2000 + 3252

Thread 9 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x17013d240.events
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001911ef278 0x1911ee000 + 4728
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910dd6b4 0x1910c9000 + 83636
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910dcc5c 0x1910c9000 + 80988
3   CoreLocation                    0x000000019a489078 0x19a486000 + 12408
4   CoreLocation                    0x000000019a48e118 0x19a486000 + 33048
5   CoreLocation                    0x000000019a48df18 0x19a486000 + 32536
6   CoreLocation                    0x000000019a4d9e88 0x19a486000 + 343688
7   CoreLocation                    0x000000019a4d64f0 0x19a486000 + 328944
8   CoreLocation                    0x000000019a4d6414 0x19a486000 + 328724
9   CoreLocation                    0x000000019a4d7a80 0x19a486000 + 334464
10  libxpc.dylib                    0x000000019130784c 0x191302000 + 22604
11  libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000191305358 0x191302000 + 13144
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910caa70 0x1910c9000 + 6768
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910ce5f0 0x1910c9000 + 22000
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910d8964 0x1910c9000 + 63844
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910cda2c 0x1910c9000 + 18988
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910d8964 0x1910c9000 + 63844
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910ce2cc 0x1910c9000 + 21196
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910d8964 0x1910c9000 + 63844
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910ce2cc 0x1910c9000 + 21196
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910d9950 0x1910c9000 + 67920
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910e0170 0x1910c9000 + 94576
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912d2fbc 0x1912d2000 + 4028
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912d2cac 0x1912d2000 + 3244

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912d2ca8 0x1912d2000 + 3240

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001742e4d37
    x4: 0x0000000190c67b07   x5: 0x000000016fd47580   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x000000000000000b  x11: 0x000000000000000b
   x12: 0x0000000000000010  x13: 0x000000019245dc0e  x14: 0x0000030000000300  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001b84ecb40  x21: 0x000000016fd47580  x22: 0x00000001b84f3bb8  x23: 0x0000000000000001
   x24: 0x00000001740175b0  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000001  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x000000016fd47be0   fp: 0x000000016fd474e0   lr: 0x00000001912d7264
    sp: 0x000000016fd474c0   pc: 0x000000019120d014 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really a true solution to the problem, but I fixed this by upgrading my PhoneGap version as well as all of the libraries involved.